# RAID1 /dev/md0 showing up as /dev/md126 after reboot

Tags: partitioning, raid, mdadm

I've already configured the file:

```
/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

with the outcome of :

```
mdadm --detail --scan
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=compute2:0 UUID=4e0dd53b:c29a881a:795286f7:a649ff4a
ARRAY /dev/md1 metadata=1.2 name=compute2:1 UUID=8101d88b:0599ff9b:f4a96414:2f93b5f4
```

and then ran the command

```
 update-initramfs -u
```

Then rebooted but it still the devices /dev/md0 and /dev/md1 disappear afterwards, and /dev/md126 and /dev/md127 are active first after reboot.

Those devices are now present in the /proc/mdstat and /proc/partitions files.
Then doing mdadm -S /dev/md126 and mdadm -S /dev/md127, and the other devices i.e. /dev/md0 and /dev/md1 show up in /proc/mdstat and /proc/partition again.

Can someone help on this matter?